# Attestation on fork or reorg

Tags: forks, validators, chain-reorganization, attestations

Suppose a validator needs to do attestation for slot N. It sends the attestation but later discovers that there was a fork or reorg on slot N-1 (and that he attested for the wrong fork). Should he produce another attestation for the correct fork?

Answer (score 1):

No, a validator should never produce two concurrent attestations to avoid being slashed for *Double vote*.

Here is the condition that would slash a double vote where the first vote is `data_1` and the second vote is `data_2`:

```py
        # Double vote
        (data_1 != data_2 and data_1.target.epoch == data_2.target.epoch)
```

As you can see, a validator should not make two different attestations for the same epoch.